# AngularJS: ngInclude and dynamic URLs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

I'm using the `ngInclude` directive to load HTML fragments. Now I'm looking for the best way to pass a dynamic URL. I know I can create the URL with string concatenation:

```js
<ng-include src="'/foo/' + fooId + '/bar/' + barId + '/baz/' + bazId"></ng-include>
```

In my eyes this is a bit ugly.

`ngHref` and `ngSrc` for example, accept URLs containing `{{}}` markup. IMHO this syntax is much cleaner:

```js
<img ng-src="/foo/{{fooId}}/bar/{{barId}}/baz/{{bazId}}"/>
<a ng-href="/foo/{{fooId}}/bar/{{barId}}/baz/{{bazId}}"/>
```

Is there a better way to pass dynamic URLs to ngInclude?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Not sure if this is "better" or not, but you could create a function on your scope to encapsulate this.

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.fooId = "123";
  $scope.barId = "abc";
  $scope.bazId = "abc";

  $scope.templateUrl = function() {
    return "/foo/"+ $scope.fooId +"/bar/"+ $scope.barId +"/baz/"+ $scope.bazId;
  }
});
```

Then you would use it like so...

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ng-include src="templateUrl()"></ng-include>
</div>
```

Here's a live example of this type of thing: http://plnkr.co/edit/Lu3icqPgg1dpNCj6a3Dn?p=preview

Comment: Is the callback function necessary? Why not affecting directly $scope.templateUrl = "/foo/"... ?

Comment: The callback isn't the only way. You could certainly create a `templateUrl` property on scope. You would just need a consistent way of updating the value of `templateUrl` anytime `fooId`, `barId`, `bazId` are changed.

Comment: So, using a callback will update "automagically" the value of templateUrl whereas affecting directly templateUrl won't?

Comment: That's not correct. You can achieve the same result either way. I think that using a function here is easier.

Comment: @jessegavin i tried loading page after a pause in that case its not working, what I need to achieve is, load page on basis of certain response from server so i created small pause to give a test.    $scope.templateUrl = function () {

      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("log after 5 seconds");
        return "app/rsa/summary/summary.html";
      }, 5000);
    }

Comment: Do we have a callback event in angular that tells whether the DOM has loaded in this case,  as the template might change very often and DOM too.

Answer (score 4):

@jessegavin is better use this code

```
  <ng-include ng-init="tmplUrl = templateUrl();" src="tmplUrl"></ng-include>
```

if you will use this way

```
<ng-include src="templateUrl()"></ng-include>
```

templateUrl calls a few times. (3 times). try console.log. i think because of $scope varibles

$scope.templateUrl = function() {
    var url = "/foo/"+ $scope.fooId +"/bar/"+ $scope.barId +"/baz/"+ $scope.bazId;
    console.log(url);
    return url;
  }